# Prevent scheduled post being published if date/time is past current date/time

Tags: posts, date-time, publish, notifications

I'm looking for a function at prevents a scheduled post being published/updated (with a popup warning or text next to the publish button) if the post's date/time is equal to or less than the current date/time. I have a plugin that allows all scheduled posts to be visible immediately.

Appreciated

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you expect the post status will be at the time? What's to stop the posts date/time being edited? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: The post status at the time will be dependent on whether the post is being published for the first time or edited. Nothing is to stop the post being edited, I simply don't want the post to be able to be published/updated IF the post date is equal to or less than the current date, that's it. I'm trying to achieve a job posting board, very broadly speaking.

Comment: There's a problem here in that if I flag something to be published in 2 months time using scheduled publishing, it sets the posts as published but puts the publish date in the future

Comment: There's no problem as I said there's a current date time condition.

Comment: It means you can't use the publish status as a flag, if I create a post and make a mistake, and it's going to be public in a weeks time, I can't update the post to fix the problem, but it isn't "published" per say. If I add a date check, then I can bypass the check by moving the publish date into the future then moving it back after making changes

Comment: So you're saying what I want can't be done.

Comment: No, just that it's not quite so simple as it first appears. A good answer will need to take your need, and reword it to be more nuanced taking into account the information I mentioned

Comment: I've updated my question